# Close UDP socket with no socket.close()

Tags: python, sockets, shell, ubuntu

Having a python program which open **UDP socket**

```
receiveSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
receiveSock.bind(("", portReceive))
```

It sometimes happens that the program fails or I terminate it in running time and it doesn't reach to

```
receiveSock.close()
```

So that at the next time I trying to run this program I get

```
receiveSock.bind(("",portReceive))
  File "<string>", line 1, in bind
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

How could I close this socket using shell command (or any other useful idea)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

```
try:
   # your socket operations
finally:
   # close your socket
```

Or, for newer versions of Python:

```
with open_the_socket() as the_socket:
   # do stuff with the_socket
```

The [`with statement`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) will close the socket when the block is finished, or the program exits.

Comment: I thought about `finally` but in interrupt closing (`crl+Z`) it doesn't enter to that `finally` .

Comment: `CTRL+Z` suspends tasks in UNIX/Linux; so you wouldn't expect the socket to be closed.

Comment: `CTRL+C` also doen't enter to `finally` .

Comment: @URL87 huh? It does. If it doesn't check your signal handling filters (parent shell(s)) and your assumptions. Proof: http://pastebin.com/iY8LQDyK